# Add a column to data frame n days before an observation

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I need an more efficient way to add a marker that shows that an observation is registered 3 days before a specific date. The problem is that these dates are not necessarily consecutive i.e. they can be missing, yet I need the marker to ignore the missing days. The example below illustrates the problem and what I need more clearly:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame("Date" = c(as_date(0:9)), ID = rep(paste0("ID", 1:3), each = 10))
df <- df[-c(5, 13, 24),]

date_before <- "1970-01-07"

df[, "three_days_before"] <- 0

for(i in df$ID){

  cond <- df[, "ID"] == i & 
    df[, "Date"] == date_before

  before_n <- (which(cond)-3):(which(cond)-1)

  df[before_n, "three_days_before"] <- 1

}

df
```

The loop gives me what I need (three days are marked each time regardless their inclusion in the data.frame), yet it takes quite a long time to calculate on a larger data set. Can someone recommend a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Apply a rolling window separately for each `ID`.  The rolling window function checks whether any of the next 3 elements of Date equal `date_before`. 
(Specifying a width of `list(1:3)` says to use offsets 1, 2 and 3 which means the next 3 ahead.) Note that there are no next 3 elements for the last value so we use `fill` to fill it in.  We add 0 to convert from logical to numeric. This solution involves only two lines of code and no explicit looping.

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x) rollapply(x, list(1:3), FUN = any, partial = TRUE, fill = FALSE)
transform(df, before = ave(Date == date_before, ID, FUN = roll) + 0)
```

giving:

```
         Date  ID before
1  1970-01-01 ID1      0
2  1970-01-02 ID1      0
3  1970-01-03 ID1      1
4  1970-01-04 ID1      1
6  1970-01-06 ID1      1
7  1970-01-07 ID1      0
8  1970-01-08 ID1      0
9  1970-01-09 ID1      0
10 1970-01-10 ID1      0
11 1970-01-01 ID2      0
12 1970-01-02 ID2      0
14 1970-01-04 ID2      1
15 1970-01-05 ID2      1
16 1970-01-06 ID2      1
17 1970-01-07 ID2      0
18 1970-01-08 ID2      0
19 1970-01-09 ID2      0
20 1970-01-10 ID2      0
21 1970-01-01 ID3      0
22 1970-01-02 ID3      0
23 1970-01-03 ID3      1
25 1970-01-05 ID3      1
26 1970-01-06 ID3      1
27 1970-01-07 ID3      0
28 1970-01-08 ID3      0
29 1970-01-09 ID3      0
30 1970-01-10 ID3      0
```

**2)** This could also be expressed as a pipeline where `roll` is from above:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(before = roll(Date == date_before)) %>%
   ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution using `difftime` and `cumsum`:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(
        is_before = difftime(as_date(date_before), Date) >= 0,
        three_days_before = as.numeric((max(cumsum(is_before)) - cumsum(is_before)) %in% 1:3)) %>%
    select(-is_before) %>%
    as.data.frame()
#         Date  ID three_days_before
#1  1970-01-01 ID1                 0
#2  1970-01-02 ID1                 0
#3  1970-01-03 ID1                 1
#4  1970-01-04 ID1                 1
#5  1970-01-06 ID1                 1
#6  1970-01-07 ID1                 0
#7  1970-01-08 ID1                 0
#8  1970-01-09 ID1                 0
#9  1970-01-10 ID1                 0
#10 1970-01-01 ID2                 0
#11 1970-01-02 ID2                 0
#12 1970-01-04 ID2                 1
#13 1970-01-05 ID2                 1
#14 1970-01-06 ID2                 1
#15 1970-01-07 ID2                 0
#16 1970-01-08 ID2                 0
#17 1970-01-09 ID2                 0
#18 1970-01-10 ID2                 0
#19 1970-01-01 ID3                 0
#20 1970-01-02 ID3                 0
#21 1970-01-03 ID3                 1
#22 1970-01-05 ID3                 1
#23 1970-01-06 ID3                 1
#24 1970-01-07 ID3                 0
#25 1970-01-08 ID3                 0
#26 1970-01-09 ID3                 0
#27 1970-01-10 ID3                 0
```

Explanation: We group entries by `ID`; `is_before` flags entries *at or before* `date_before`; we then flag the first three rows *before* `date_before` with `(max(cumsum(is_before)) - cumsum(is_before)) %in% 1:3)`.

---

### Sample data

```
library(lubridate);
df <- data.frame("Date" = c(as_date(0:9)), ID = rep(paste0("ID", 1:3), each = 10))
df <- df[-c(5, 13, 24),]
date_before <- "1970-01-07"
```